# Unbinding Evil's C-w mappings?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying out Emacs with Evil mode.

I'd like to use <kbd>C-w</kbd> as a prefix for my own window manipulation shortcuts that are defined globally, not just for buffers with Evil mode. I have the following code in my init.el

```
(define-prefix-command 'my-window-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-window-map)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "h") 'windmove-left)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "j") 'windmove-down)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "k") 'windmove-up)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "l") 'windmove-right)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "v") 'split-window-right)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "b") 'split-window-below)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "x") 'delete-window)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "o") 'delete-other-windows)
```

This works if Evil is not loaded, but when I load Evil it overwrites any conflicting maps (<kbd>C-w b</kbd> for example).

I can also comment out L106-158 and L236 from [evil-maps.el](https://gitorious.org/evil/evil/source/7117670681d09304d67768bcef4b23e4028cfe2d:evil-maps.el#L106-158) and my maps work, but I would rather not deal with modifying evil-maps.el.

Is there a way to prevent Evil from using the <kbd>C-w</kbd> prefix, or unset it afterwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `C-w` prefix switches you *into* the `evil-window-map`, so undefining `C-w` in that map will not help.  The key mapping in the "evil-maps" file that is relevant sets `C-w` in `evil-motion-state-map` to `evil-window-map`, and that binding is inherited by *most of* the other evil maps.  You could set that keybinding to `nil` so you can use your own binding in this way:

```
(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-w" nil))
```

However, neither `evil-insert-state-map` nor `evil-emacs-state-map` inherit in this way (I'm pretty sure), so you'll need to unbind in those maps as well.  So use the following to unbind in all 3 maps in one fell swoop:

```
(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  (dolist (map '(evil-motion-state-map
                 evil-insert-state-map
                 evil-emacs-state-map))
    (define-key (eval map) "\C-w" nil)))
```

You could also replace the `nil` with `'my-window-map` to rebind to your own mapping, but it's probably already exposed via your call to `global-set-key`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do something after some package is loaded is using `eval-after-load`.  In your example, you could put this in your .emacs:

```
(defun set-control-w-shortcuts ()
  (define-prefix-command 'my-window-map)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-window-map)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "h") 'windmove-left)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "j") 'windmove-down)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "k") 'windmove-up)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "l") 'windmove-right)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "v") 'split-window-right)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "b") 'split-window-below)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "x") 'delete-window)
  (define-key my-window-map (kbd "o") 'delete-other-windows))


(set-control-w-shortcuts)

(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  '(progn
     (define-key evil-window-map "\C-w" 'nil)
     (set-control-w-shortcuts)))
```

Comment: Yes on the `eval-after-load`, but `evil-window-map` is the wrong map for this purpose.  See my answer about the evil maps.

Comment: for some coming from vim using arrow keys to navigate like me:
`(define-key my-window-map (kbd "<left>") 'windmove-left)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "<down>") 'windmove-down)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "<up>") 'windmove-up)
(define-key my-window-map (kbd "<right>") 'windmove-right))`